# Laravel create a repo using in php github api

Tags: php, laravel, github-api

I'm trying out this prototype app where I can learn more about using api and laravel so i thought of a crud app with the github api using laravel so far I can pull repos no problem to show but I'm trying to create a repo now and I'm stuck if an api jedi can shine a path I'd appreciate thanks ahead.

This is the message I get from githubs api in $response :
    "{"message":"Not   Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}"

```
public function createGithubRepo()
{
    $collection = auth()->user()->providers;
    $plucked = $collection->pluck('token');
    $plucked->all();

    $token = $plucked[0];

    $url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' . 'david-dacruz/localhost/contents/file.md';

      $data = [
                 'message' => 'my localhost commit message',
                 'committer' => [
                 'name' => 'David Dacruz',
                 'email' => 'dvddcrz@gmail.com'
    ],
            'content' => 'my localhost commit message bXkgbmV3IGZpbGUgY29udGVudHM='

    ];

    $data = json_encode($data);

    $curl_url = $url;
    $curl_token_auth = 'Authorization: token ' . $token;
    $ch = curl_init($curl_url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'User-Agent: david-dacruz', $curl_token_auth ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    dd($response); 
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($response);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: if you just starting to develop i suggest use laravel packge for github api https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub